# copy a c string into a char array

Tags: c++, arrays

New to C, still getting a grasp on pointers. I'm trying to add a copy of a c string into a char array such that

```
char temp[40];
temp[0] = 'a';
temp[1] = 'b';
temp[2] = 'c';
temp[3] = NULL;
char *container[40] = {0};
strcpy(container[0], temp);
cout << container[0] << endl;
```

prints "abc". Trying to make a copy because temp is constantly being replaced with new characters and a pointer to temp obviously won't suffice as i want to do this after abc is printed.

```
char temp[40];
temp[0] = 'd';
temp[1] = 'e';
temp[2] = 'f';
temp[3] = NULL;
char *container[40] = {0};
strcpy(container[1], temp);
cout << container[1] << endl;
```

prints 'def'.
P.S this is what i have so far, but it doesn't work. I'm not too sure if im using strcpy incorrectly, but any alternatives would be helpful.

Comment: You're not using C but C++.

Comment: `container[0]` is just a pointer to a `char`.  You must point it to enough memory before you call `strcpy`.

Comment: C or C?? Which is it? These are C techniques, but the C++ language. And you use both terms in your question....

Comment: Also, a C string _is_ a `char` array....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `strcpy` correctly, but you are not giving it proper memory. That is why both your programs have undefined behavior - they write to memory pointed by uninitialized pointers.

To fix this, allocate memory to each element of `container` using `malloc`:

```
char temp[40];
temp[0] = 'a';
temp[1] = 'b';
temp[2] = 'c';
temp[3] = NULL;
char *container[40] = {0};
container[0] = (char*)malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
strcpy(container[0], temp);
cout << container[0] << endl;
```

You need to add `1` to the result of `strlen` in order to accommodate the null terminator of your C string.
Note that the cast of `malloc` is necessary only because you are using C++; in C, the cast in front of `malloc` can be dropped.

**Note:** I assume that this is a learning exercise to learn ways to work with "raw" pointers, because C++ provides much better facilities for working with strings. In particular, your container could be replaced with a `std::vector<std::string>` which would grow dynamically as you add items to it, and manage its own memory, thus eliminating the need to use `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Comment: Might be worthwhile warning against doing any of this in the first place? Also you misspelt "container".

Comment: question. would this be the equiv. to char *container[] = {"abc" ,"def"}. behind the scenes are the parameters being stored as cstrings and the memory is allocated for it? note: i realise they're static values.

Comment: @zzzzz Yes, this would be equivalent in terms of a memory layout, except for two things: the container would have two elements instead of 40, and you would need to declare it `const char *container[40]` with a `const`, because C++ requires C strings to be declared constant.